# pass var to another screen in flutter cameras = await availableCameras();

Tags: flutter, dart

i am implementing camera this [lib](https://pub.dev/packages/camera/example)  this library collects camera in the main file like this

```
List<CameraDescription> cameras = [];

Future<void> main() async {
  // Fetch the available cameras before initializing the app.
  try {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    cameras = await availableCameras();
  } on CameraException catch (e) {
    logError(e.code, e.description);
  }
  runApp(CameraApp());
}
```

The problem is that i want to use this cameras list in another class which is not connected in main() function i dont know how to use these cameras in 3rd screen.

For eg if i have 4 screen main()=>1st screen=> 2nd screen=> 3rd screen=> 4th screen. Now the cameras are initialising the main but i want them in 4th screen.

Answer (score 0):

use state management for pass data to another screen.

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/intro